# How can I create a Serilog enricher that reads from HttpContext.TraceIdentifier?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, action-filter, serilog

I've recently integrated Serilog into several .NET Standard class libraries, including some class libraries that are used by MVC 6 projects. What I'd like to do is enrich log entries with `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier`. I wrote an action filter that sets `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` to a `Correlation-ID` request header value, if present:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    StringValues correlationIds;
    Guid correlationId;

    if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Constants.CorrelationIdHeaderName, out correlationIds) || correlationIds.Count != 1 || !Guid.TryParse(correlationIds[0], out correlationId))
    {
        correlationId = _guidFactory.Random();

        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(Constants.CorrelationIdHeaderName, correlationId.ToString("D"));
    }

    context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier = correlationId.ToString("D");

    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

The problem is, how do I make Serilog aware, for the life of this request, of the correlation ID? Since it doesn't appear as though there is an `HttpContext.Current` property, I'm not sure how to create an enricher that will work. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you need an enricher for this.

Putting `{RequestId}` into the sink's `outputTemplate` gives me an ID like "0HL0GJPLR7AOD". If I set `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` right before logging something then `{RequestId}` gives me exactly that ID so custom IDs also work with `{RequestId}`.

I think `{RequestId}` is a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging feature but it works out of the box with serilog (at least when you are using Serilog.Extensions.Logging).

**Update**: Don't forget to configure `Enrich.FromLogContext()`.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: How would I do this using `JsonFormatter`? There is no `outputTemplate` parameter in that case since Serilog serializes objects.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr I don't know about `JsonFormatter` but `CompactJsonFormatter` automatically includes all the event properties like `RequestId` as JSON object properties like `"RequestId":"0HL0NKROIGJ8O"`

Comment: Cool, thank you. I am working on this now; I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Everything you mentioned checks out! Thanks so much for this.

Comment: @user764754 - Doesn't seem to work on .Net Core 3.1, I just get empty string for RequestId in my log file

Comment: Is it possible to use `Activity.Current?.Id` instead of `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` ?